# remove notify callback from chain of Q promise

Tags: javascript, q

how can I remove the notify callback of a promise? Assume the following jsfiddle

```
http://jsfiddle.net/anand_anand84/n6syLacs/2/
```

What should be done if I want to remove the stepC from promise1 callback list such that the `console.log("HEADER Received =", data);` is not printed.

```
var i = 0;
var deferred = Q.defer();

var simualteQuotes = function () {
    deferred.notify(i++);
    return "ret 1"
};

var getQuote = function(scrip){
    //Contains a map containing promises and corresponding scrips;
    //returns the promise of the scrip
   return deferred.promise;
}
var stepA = function (data) {
    console.log("Chart Received =", data);
};
var stepB = function (data) {
    console.log("MarketWatch Received =", data);
};
var stepC = function (data) {
    console.log("HEADER Received =", data);
};


// then() can be used multiple times. It's like, for each then(), a callback is registered.
// and when the promise is fulfilled, all the registered callbacks are called

var promise1 = deferred.promise;
var promiseA = promise1.progress(stepA);
var promiseB = promise1.progress(stepB);
var promiseC = promise1.progress(stepC);

setInterval(simualteQuotes, 6000);
```

Comment: Please put your code in the question, instead of a link to a fiddle.

Comment: Um, why are you using a deferred at all here? It's never resolved. Looks like promises are the wrong tool for this task. Also, notify callbacks are not supposed to be removed. You can however easily wrap their actions in a conditional.

Comment: comment out var promiseC = promise1.progress(stepC);?